# Is there a password security/xss issue if I allow all possible characters in a password?

Tags: security, asp-classic, passwords, xss

Is there a reason for concern of an XSS attack on a ASP Classic site, which allows all characters in a password field? If yes, how can it be prevented without restricting characters?

If the password is never displayed anywhere, I'm assuming this isn't an issue.

(And yes, passwords shouldn't be *able* to be displayed, but assuming this is the scenario.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if correctly encoded when output, but then again you should probably implement a policy where passwords are only input, never output. That would also solve your XSS issue.

Read this for more info on XSS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 0):

The issue (and this is in any language/framework, not just ASP/VBScript) is almost always with how you handle the password, not what you allow (discussion on proper password requirements aside).

There are a ton of questions on XSS (which you should read) and deal with the particulars of data handling and what can/can't be exploited in that fashion.

There are a ton of questions on password security (which you should read) and deal with the particulars of password requirements, encryption, etc.